# What is first-generation?

Tags: american-english

what is the first-generation and so-and-so generation?
How am I supposed to understand if someone says they're something-geneartion?

Comment: Have you looked this up in your dictionary? What does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can mean one of the following:

1. The first in a series of products, eg: first-generation Xbox, or first-generation Honda Civic, or the first-generation of color TVs.
2. Referring to someone born in a country whose parents were from another country. For example, if you were born in America but your parents were born in Europe you could be considered a 'first-generation American'.
3. Sometimes, contradictory to the above, it can also mean someone who has immigrated to another country, ie: the first-generation to immigrate. If I was born in Europe but immigrated to America I might be considered a 'first-generation immigrant'.

Answer (score 0):

"**first-generation**" means that something that came first, appeared first, was created first.

The same applies to all next generations.